# Are there any GameBoy Advance emulators for OS X Lion?

Tags: macos, switching

As a prior Windows user, on the Mac I miss some popular video game console emulators like VisualBoyAdvance or ZSNES. Especially the lack of a good Game Boy Advance emulator is bugging me.

So my question is: Is there a good GBA emulator out for OS X Lion? No PPC apps please.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com is not a replacement for a simple search engine look-up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some references. I don't have any personal experience with them.

[Attack of the Mac Emulators: Retro Games on OS X](http://mac.appstorm.net/roundups/games/attack-of-the-mac-emulators-retro-games-on-os-x/), April 22, 2010

[Richard Bannister's BSNES for Mac OS X](http://bannister.org/software/index.htm). A note there indicates that it is not yet compiled for Lion.

[Links to Emulators at Pure-Mac.com](http://www.pure-mac.com/emu.html)

Answer (score 0):

I thought I should provide a 2016 answer, since I had the same question. I downloaded **Boycott Advance** from [emuparadise](http://www.emuparadise.me/Nintendo_Gameboy_Advance_Emulators/Mac_OS_X/Boycott_Advance/223) and it works like a charm.

It will download a .zip file, unzip it and just double click on the Boycott Advance file you will see.

Now, given that you already have a ROM downloaded, I had [leafGreen](http://www.emuparadise.me/Nintendo_Gameboy_Advance_ROMs/Pokemon_Leaf_Green_(U)(Independent)/44875)..... go to the Boycott Advance toolbar (on the top of the screen) and click File -> Open and select your ROM, and you be fine! Have fun... :)

---

In case you are good in Pokemon, contact me (see my profile) for a battle in the online simulator Pokemon Showdown (it's really simple, you just assemble your team, give me your username in Showdown and I will challenge you)!